# Casting a large number type to a smaller type

Tags: c++, types

I've had a good look around and can't find a similar question so apologies if it has been asked before.

I'm just playing around with types and numbers and I am wondering if the following behaviour can be guaranteed.
If I declare 2 variables as

```
unsigned char BIT_8 = 0;
unsigned short int BIT_16 = 0xFF01;
```

and then do the following (ignoring C style cast for now, unless that can affect it?)

```
cout << "BIT_16: " << BIT_16 << "\n";
cout << "BIT_8: " << (int)BIT_8 << "\n";
BIT_8 = BIT_16;
cout << "BIT_8 after: " << (int)BIT_8 << "\n";
BIT_8 = BIT_16 >> 8;
cout << "BIT_8 after shift: " << (int)BIT_8 << "\n";
```

I get the output

```
BIT_16: 65281
BIT_8: 0
BIT_8 after: 1
BIT_8 after shift: 255
```

Is it guaranteed that if I cast a 16 bit type to an 8 bit type that the leading byte will be lost? or is it undefined and the above results are luck?

Comment: little - targeted at x86

Comment: Endianness has no effect here.

Comment: Endianness matters only when considering the order of the bytes, which is not the case here.

Comment: The C spec refers to the "most significant" bytes as the ones that are dropped. This means that the behavior is well-defined, regardless of little endianness or big endianness.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that if I cast a 16 bit type to an 8 bit type that the leading byte will be lost?

Depends on whether you are working with signed or unsigned types (see section 4.7 §2 and §3):

> If the destination type is **unsigned**, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation).]
>
> If the destination type is **signed**, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is **implementation-defined**.

Since you are working with unsigned types, the behavior is well-specified.

Comment: In C, that implement-defined behaviour can explicitly include raising an implementation-defined signal, such as SIGFPE. I don't know if C++ includes similar wording, but in any case, it can implicitly include that.