# How does explicit casting work in C?

Tags: c, casting, explicit

Let's say I have the following code lines:

```
int a; // 4-byte-integer
char b, c, d, e;

b = (char)(a >> 24);
c = (char)(a >> 16);
d = (char)(a >> 8);
e = (char)a;
```

Let's also assume that the system is storing the bytes in little-endian mode and `a = 100`.

When using the explicit cast like that, do the left-most bytes disappear?
I guess that after executing the above lines, the variables will hold these values: `b=100, c=0, d=0, e=0`. Is it right?

Comment: Unless you use `unsigned` variables this will cause `undefined behaviour`. Then the most significant part will be truncated. The endianness is not relevant in this example.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752567/casting-a-large-number-type-to-a-smaller-type?

Comment: @WeatherVane is it undefined behavior or unexpected behavior? The behavior of the sign bit is deterministic.

Comment: @nicomp As long as the behaviour is unexpected, why shouldn't be undefined?

Comment: Right-shifting a negative signed integer is _implementation-defined_, not _undefined_ behaviour. The standard says (§6.5.7): _The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1 / 2 ** E2`. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined._ (I used `2 ** E2` for 2 raised to the power of E2 since `2<sup>E2</sup>` doesn't work in comments, even outside code quotes (2<sup>E2</sup> — see!).

Comment: @nicomp: right shifting a signed value is *implementation defined*, but storing a value outside its boundaries into a signed type is *undefined behavior*.  Sad and quite unexpected, but true, and far reaching consequences with modern optimizing compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guess right!  But your explanation is not completely correct:

- The behavior of the above code does not depend on the endianness of the system: if `int` is 32 bits and `char` 8 bits, `a >> 24` is the high order byte and `a & 255` the low order byte, for all possible endianness possibilities.
- explicit casts as `(char)` are not needed, because C does implicit conversion of the expression value to the type of the assignment destination.  I suppose the programmer wrote it this way to silence a compiler warning.  Microsoft compilers are notoriously vocal about losing precision in assignments.
- the *leftmost* bytes do not *disappear*, the value is computed modulo the size of `char`, hopefully 8 bits in your case, so `(char)a` is essentially the same as `a & 255`.  But if `char` is signed, this behavior is not actually well defined by the Standard if the value exceeds `CHAR_MAX`.  It is wise to use `unsigned` types for this kind of bit manipulation.