# Bit shift leads to strange type conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bit-shift

The following code compiles without warning:

```
std::uint16_t a = 12;
std::uint16_t b = a & 0x003f;
```

However, performing a bit shift along with the bitwise and leads to an 'implicit cast warning':

```
std::uint16_t b = (a & 0x003f) << 10; // Warning generated.
```

Both gcc and clang complain that there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `uint16_t`, yet I fail to see why  introducing the bit shift would cause the right hand expression to suddenly evaluate to an `int`.

EDIT: For clang, I compiled with the `-std=c++14 -Weverything` flags; for gcc, I compiled with the `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wconversion` flags.

Comment: Expression evaluates to an `int` in both cases. Would you provide compiler settings (maybe an online example) for this warning? I don't get this warning in a quick experiment, neither from GCC nor from clang

Comment: @AnT Try `-Wconversion`. You should see the warning then.

Comment: _"If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion. "_ [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925291/bit-shifting-left-and-discarding-bits?noredirect=1#comment61414105_36925291).

Comment: @ZDF The problem seems deeper than that. `static_cast`ing all quantities to `std::uint16_t` doesn't make the warnings go away.

Comment: @Alessandro Power: Static-casting operands is not supposed to make it go away - they are immediately promoted back to `int` anyway. The only thing that you can static_cast in this case (to make it go away) is the final result.

Comment: You will get the warning as long as you use types that are narrower than an `int`. I would use `unsigned int` instead of `uint16_t` and cast it once I am done with the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yet I fail to see why introducing the bit shift would cause the right hand expression to suddenly evaluate to an int.

I think you misinterpret the warning. In both cases expression evaluate to `int` but in the first case result will always fit in `uint16_t`, in the second case it will not. Looks like the compiler is smart enough to detect that and generates warning only in the second case.

Comment: @Ant because that will still fit in `uint16_t`, can you try binary `or` instead?

Comment: @Slava: Yes, got it. Somehow I forgot to replace the `&`.

Comment: `unsigned char a = 1;  unsigned char b = (a & 0x01) << 4;` will yield the same warning. `unsigned char b = (1 & 0x01) << 4;` will fall in "smart enough".

Comment: @ZDF nobody is perfect

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic): *"If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes **integral promotion**."*

For instance:

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = a << byte(1);
```

1. `a` and `1` are promoted to `int`: `int(a)` and `int(byte(1))`.
2. `a` is shifted one position to left: `int result = int(a) << int(byte(1))` (the result is an `int`).
3. `result` is stored in `b`. Since `int` is wider than `byte` an warning will be issued.

If the operands are **constant expressions**, a compiler might be able to compute the result at compile time and issue an warning iff the result does not fit in destination:

```
byte b = 1 << 1; // no warning: does not exceed 8 bits
byte b = 1 << 8; // warning: exceeds 8 bits
```

Or, using `constexpr`:

```
constexpr byte a = 1;
byte b = a << 1; // no warning: it fits in 8 bits
byte b = a << 8; // warning: it does not fit in 8 bits
```

Answer (score 4):

Doing any arithmetic with integer types always is preceded by promotion to at least (sometimes, but not in this case using gcc, `unsigned`) `int`. As you can see by [this example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3BDwynlJjAoh8JO4), this applies to you first, warning-less variant too.

The probably best way to get around these (admittedly often surprising) integer promotion rules would be to use an `unsigned int` (or `uint32_t` on common platforms) from the get go.

If you cannot or don't want to use the bigger type, you can just `static_cast` the result of the whole expression back to `std::uint16_t`:

```
std::uint16_t b = static_cast<std::uint16_t>((a & 0x003f) << 10);
```

This will correctly result in the RHS-value mod 2^16.