# Size of different data types causes confusion

Tags: c

I was working on some C programs and I had this confusion lately, that hit me again:
suppose I have a function that takes a 32 bit size variable, and another that takes 8 bits, and we have to transfer data from the 32 bit variable to the 8 bit variable.

Here is a sample program that I have confusion with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_OF_BLOCK 512
uint32* a = NULL; // for read
uint8* b = NULL;  // for write

int read_register(uint32* rbuff)
{
    uint8 i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK / 4; i++) // here one
        rbuff[i] = read_from_32_bit_reg();  // read incrementally on each iteration
    return 0;
}

int write_register(uint8* wbuff)
{
    uint8 i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++) // here one
        write_reg(wbuff[i]);            // point 2
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    a = (uint32*)malloc(sizeof(uint32) * 128); // contains 4096 bits
    b = (uint8*)malloc(sizeof(uint8) * 512);   // contains 4096 bits
    read_register(a);
    b = (uint8*)a; // point 1
    write(0x0080000, b);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

1) So I get all 512 bits in 128, 4 byte locations. If I assign this value to a 8 bit location, which side of bits I am stripping off? MSB 8 bits, or LSB 8 bits on a intel PC.

2) I am still transferring 4096 bits, and 'b' have the address of a's addressed location. Am I still transferring all correct values from a?

Its basically is a confusion, and couldn't make up my mind, how to approach it.

P.S. The term is called narrowing but if I do things same way that I did, assigning address from a 32 bit variable to the 8 bit variable, and goes through on 8 bit increments, it should be able to get all the values? I don't think narrowing happens in pointer variable case, as both are int size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting a large number type to a smaller type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752567/casting-a-large-number-type-to-a-smaller-type)

Comment: In pointer case how it is same?

Comment: 32*128 is not 512 bits, it is 512 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

First a remark: when you use *bits* in

```
a = (uint32 *)malloc(sizeof(uint32)*128);//contains 512 bits
```

you are wrong: you should have written `...//contains 512 bytes`

Then you have two ways of passing from integer types of one size to a smaller size:

- by conversion:

  ```
  uint32_t a = 259;
  uint8_t b = a; // perfectly defined for unsigned types: retains the low order bits here 3
  ```

  formally the n1256 draft for C99 standard says:

  > Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
  >   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
  >   until the value is in the range of the new type
- by aliasing (type punning):

  ```
  uint32_t a = 259;
  uint8_t b = *((uint8_t) &a); // LSB on Intel so 3 but 0 on a big endian system
  ```

  A pointer to any object can always be converted to a pointer to a char (or unsigned char). As `uint8_t` can only be an `unsigned char` (*), the pointer conversion is valid and will return in sequence all the bytes of the representation of the `uint32_t`... whose value is *implementation dependent*. An Intel PC normally uses a 2's complement little endian architecture so you will get the LSB, still `3`. But it would be the MSB (0) on a big endian architecture.

  But in the general case, accessing a value of one type with a non compatible type is Undefined Behaviour meaning that a compiler is free to do anything including commenting out the offending line!

Now for your points 1 and 2. In 1 you assign a pointer to an array of `uint32_t` to a pointer to `uint8_t`. It is perfectly valid. In 2 you use that `uint8_t` pointer to access the bytes of the representation of all the `uint32_t` values of the original array. It is still perfectly valid, and you would be able to rebuild the original values from their bytes, but the bytes values themselves are implementation dependent.

A last remark unrelated to the question: when you assign a pointer obtained by `malloc` to a new value, without saving it or freeing it first, you loose all possibility to later free it, causing a *memory leak*. Here you have:

```
b = (uint8 *)malloc(sizeof(uint8 )*512);//contains 512 bits
...
b = (uint8 *)a;// memory leak!
```

(*) a `char` is required to be able to represent all the values of the ASCII alphabet, so it needs at least 7 bits and all types must have size that are multiple of the `char` size. So if a `uint8_t` type exists it must be a synonym for `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chux: It is nicer like that :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, and you are asking about what happens when 32-bit unsigned integral variable are assigned to 8 bit unsigned integral variable?

This is called *narrowing*, and the result going to be the smallest unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type. This has nothing to do with endianness of the representation, as it is defined as arithmetic result, which is going to be same on every platform.

Comment: so if I do things same way as I did, assigning address from a 32 bit variable, to the 8 bit variable, and goes through on 8 bit increments, it should be able to get all the values?

Comment: It is unclear if OP is asking about that. In his code he is accessing an array of `uint32_t` with a pointer to `uint8_t`. This is not narrowing and it **has** everything to do with the endianness issue. Storing a `uint32_t` into a `uint8_t` variable is fine, but accessing the array via a different type has a very different effect.